# multiple InputReader for a single Socket

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

I have a java client/server program using ServerSocket/Socket.

In my client, I have a thread(call in ReceiverThread) which always waits for a incoming message from server. so it will block my InputReader (`myInputReader.readObject()`) .

In the client, there are also some threads, which send some stuff to the server and wait using (`myInputReader.readObject()`), until server responses. but in this case, if the server sends a response, there is a chance that the ReceiverThread catches the server response, which is not what i want.

Is there any way that i can have multiple InputStreams in a single Socket connection?

UPDATE: I have to use java Socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't make sense to listen on a socket in 2 (or more) different threads simultaneously. What you need to do is have a single "entry point" for incoming data, and have that entry point understand the context of each data block (message) and spread that to what ever logical peace of code uses it. This is a general design pattern, not a java issue.

Comment: thanks, this looks like a great idea. I will implement it like you said